# File permission with Class File

Tags: file, class, permissions

i would like to ask , because in some scenario, some class.php are not being run. even if it is in full permission,
sample.

i have a linux pc. and every time i create class.php file. i modified it like :

```
sudo chmod -Rf 777 file.class.php
```

then after that. it works on my localhost.
BUT when i transfer the file using FileZilla to other server its not running. 
even if it has Full Permission 777 in File Zilla.

Can anyone explain whats the reason behind this ?
coz i cant explain to my superior why its that running but in my localhost/Pc its running.
and they have the same File and codes inside it.

please help me..
thank you very much.

Comment: What error do you get when you try to run it?

Comment: Did you check what are the permissions on the file it has been copied to the server?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your server automatically modifies the permissions of the file when you upload it even when you have it set to something in filezilla.  I know that Windows with NTFS can sometimes strip permissions off of a file depending on how you copy/move the file.  This might be what is happening with your linux computer.

Comment: hi. thanks but its also the same in Windows.. using Github to transfer to server... the File.class.php dont run even if it has full permision.. and it has no error in error logs...